# Looking for a sci-fi book title about subterranean travel into the earth with a rocket

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find the title of a youth sci-fi book about subterranean travel into the earth with a one-man rocket. Perhaps published in the 60's or 50's.

The story follows one man traveling through a pre-drilled shaft straight down into the earth by rocket. Finally he arrives into a vast cavernous space deep inside the earth where he explores.  Thank you for any help you can offer...

Comment: I remember something vaguely similar about a team of 4 who used a rocket to explore an enormous underground cavern - so large that any (rope, cable, chain, or combination thereof) they lowered in eventually got too heavy to support itself.  Any of that ring a bell, or is that a different book?

Answer (score 4):

I just found the book!.."**THE MOHOLE MYSTERY** by Hugh Walters published 1969- (aka ***THE MOHOLE MENANCE***).

I did a search for Sci-fi books from the 60's using google and came up with a wikipedia listing of popular sci-fi books available from that era!...Great resource for future reference!!

Here's a brief plot summary from Wikipedia:

"A drilling project in Dudley in the West Midlands region of the United Kingdom hits a cavern 20 miles beneath the surface of the Earth and detects strange microbes. UNEXA send Russian Serge Smylov down to search for other forms of life in a rocket-propelled capsule but it is damaged when it hits the bottom of the cavern. Then strange creatures start attacking him..."

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154929/60s-70s-story-about-english-people-chris-et-al-going-to-mars-and-hibernating (question about the series)